# CSS line-height renders differently between safari and chrome

Tags: html, css, safari

The line-height has a different rendering between Chrome and Safari. The text "+" is not perfectly centered on Safari, while the rendering is perfect on Chrome.

[Problem visible here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MkgL.png)

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="btn">+</a>
```

CSS:

```
border-radius: 50%;
box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
display: block;
font-size: 35px;
height: 60px;
line-height: 60px;
padding: 0;
width: 60px;
```

Anybody knows why this happen?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ypJdmL)

Comment: You can show us the result on safari ?

Comment: You're mixing `rem` & `px` which may be the issue. Why not use a more modern centering method like flexbox - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/EoyBQj

Comment: What is Safari's default font size on your system?

Comment: @Paulie_D I use default font. The problem is the same when using flexbox ...

In my local code, my font-size: 3.5rem is automatically transformed into 35px.

Comment: Is it the same with all fonts - which version of Safari? I suppose it could be sub-pixel differences since you're splitting the remaining height into 12.5px each. What about *round* pixel values?

Comment: What happens if you use 6rem instead of 60px?

Comment: @Paulie_D
 No difference. My rem is automatically converted to px. 6rem = 60px for me.

Comment: @HassanSaghir I've update my post with image ;-)

Comment: It seems to me well at home